# Tutorial for Install Shield 2010 Limited Edition VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield-le

Does anyone have a tutorial that they could point me too. I am kinda confused about some of the steps in the wizard for install Shield 2010 limited edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a walkthough:

http://codesmartnothard.com/InstallShieldLimitedEditionForVisualStudio2010Walkthrough.aspx

Personally though LE feels like a highly crippled adware version of InstallShield.  If you don't push it very far you'll be OK but I'm betting Flexera is really counting on you needing to upgrade.

Comment: Probably but you know the old msi installer would probably be enough for what I need so I don't think I will push it too to the limit.

Comment: I've been thinking about it more and while it's true that LE is crippled ( for example you can't consume a DLL custom action ) it does allow you to consume merge modules which means I could write a WiX merge module that consumes the DLL custom action and injects it into the MSI.

Comment: I don't get this step like I am not sure what all the other options do. "...The “Add Project Outputs” is the primary button for adding the application files."

Comment: Do you know if possible to create a self-extracted setup with LE?

Comment: Post it as a question and I'm sure someone will answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used it and it works fine for me (much better than the msi).
I would like to state that this product is highly unstable and crashed VS 2010 constantly.
My solution was:

1) Unload installation project unless I am releasing a version.

2) Use it carefully and not stress this component

3) Learn to use VS 2010 in safe mode :)